# WebSocket4Net: The software is missing from your system

Tags: cordova, visual-studio-2013, visual-studio-cordova, websocket4net

I've installed Microsoft Visual Studio 2013 Community Edition and the Addon for Apache Cordova. After I start a new cordova I get following error message:

*We've detected issues with your system's environment configuration
WebSocket4Net The software is missing from your system. You may also have to configure it after installation. Instructions*

I have done EXACTLY what is described in the documentation:

- I have downloaded  WebSocket4Net(0.9).Binaries.zip
- From the downloaded zip file, copy net45\Release\WebSocket4Net.dll into the %ProgramFiles(x86)%\Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0\Common7\IDE\CommonExtensions\Microsoft\WebClient\Diagnostics\ToolWindows folder on your computer.

But I still get the same error message and I am desperate. I have googled for this issue and tried several things (re-installed VS, "repair" installtion) i tried WebSocket4Net(0.11) and so on...

I have Windows 7, Microsoft Visual Studio 2013 Community Edition.

Does anybody has an idea?

Comment: Are you experiencing errors when you deploy and debug your project on Ripple? if you are able to successfully debug on Ripple, the Websocket4Net issue report could be a false failure caused by a stale settings file and can be safely ignored.

Answer (score 2):

Finally I found the problem. I've installed Visual Studio to C:/Software/Visual Studio/... and NOT in %PROGRAMM_FILES% but it seems that  WebSocket4Net has to be under %PROGRAMM_FILES%